# Does Dapper's IEnumerable<T> have deferred or immediate execution?

Tags: c#, orm, ienumerable, dapper, deferred-execution

When I execute a query in Dapper and only want to retrieve a block of records, can I use .Skip().Take(), or do I need use select top n * in the SQL?

eg Given a table with 10,000 records and I only want the first 200 because my list page only shows 200 per page.  Do I run this?

```
conn.Query<Widget>("select * from Widgets").Skip((page - 1) * size).Take(size);
```

Or this:

```
conn.Query<Widget>("select top 200 * from Widgets");
```

Is Dapper's `.Query<T>` method deferred or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `SELECT TOP n...`.

The `Query<T>` method has an optional parameter `bool buffered = true`, which when true loops through the full resultset, reading each row into a `List<T>`. You could make this parameter false, and the resulting `IEnumerable<T>` would be "deferred" in the sense that the db query would not be executed until you use it, and the rows would be retrieved from the db side "one at a time" (calls `IDataReader.Read` on each iteration).

So, yes, it can be "deferred". HOWEVER, you should still use `TOP n` because otherwise you would still execute and prepare the resultset for 10000 records on the db side, although you may transport only the first n rows of those to the client.

Comment: When buffer set to false you have to worry about the connection.  If you close it before you "ToList" (or the recommended AtList), it will fail with an error.